# Does anyone have experience with this multidimensional optimization algorithm

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I recently stumbled across what looks like a very interesting [paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-Multidimensional-Bisection-Method-for-Minimizing-Baushev-Morozova/637b102def2a70373e54470843ac09b229acacb8) concerning a simplex-based bisection algorithm for multidimensional optimization.

The authors provide results from their own MATLAB code, which is apparently not publicly available.

I have not heard about this method on SE - has it been verified or used anywhere else?

[EDIT] Does anyone know of an implementation (any programming language), or failing that a more detailed description of the algorithm.  It is a 17 year old paper after all . . . or should I assume either it does not really work very well, or is being kept intentionally private (e.g. proprietary code).

[EDIT 2] More recent and "complete" (including main method!) link [here](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.5555/1379361.1379371).

[EDIT 3]  Found a citation in the literature review section of the paper [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/283645437_Multidimensional_Bisection_Search_for_Constrained_Optimization_with_Noisy_Observations), although the paper itself is not really useful to me.

Comment: From what happened with Tom Hales's proof of the [Kepler Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_conjecture), even if you provide all your code, then you may not get published without a disclaimer - until you have done a great deal of (then) trail-blazing work to demonstrate the correctness of your code.

Comment: [This](https://www.iaeng.org/WCE2007/) says that WCE 2007 papers were peer reviewed before inclusion into the proceedings. Note that that is not necessarily a high bar for a conference like this.

Comment: It specifically does not say that the code was provided to reviewers for independent testing, which would have answered my question. Unfortunately I don't think I am up to using the paper to implement it myself! So unless someone else can do it . . . think I'll edit my question.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author, Anton N. Baushev (very probably the one at the [BLTP](http://theor.jinr.ru/sql/alphsql.php?B) of the JINR)?

Comment: Well that is certainly a valid suggestion, although as a "hobbyist programmer" it would be an uncomfortable thing to attempt (I have approached a few authors on that basis in the past & got nowhere).  I will consider it though.

Comment: @RobArthan point taken, but this is not a "proof paper".  I would personally be satisfied with code that is merely sufficient to reproduce the results (or claims, if you like) in the paper itself.

Comment: @m4r35n357: understood! Good luck. I think Eric's suggestion is a very good one.